# Search engine string matching

Tags: search, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

What is the typical algorithm used by online search engines to make suggestions for misspelled words.  I'm not necessarily talking about Google, but any site with a search feature, such as as Amazon.com for instance.  Say I search for the word `"shoo"`; the site will come back and say `"did you mean: shoe"`.

Is this some variation of the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? Perhaps if they are using some full text search framework (like lucene for instance) this is built in?  Maybe fully custom?

I know the answer varies a lot, I'm just looking for an indication on how to get started with this (in an enterprise environment).

Comment: One inelegant but relevant possibility is to collect and analyze actual user data - how people revise their queries, the pages that people click on, etc. Another consideration is approximate phonetic matching such as [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)/etc.

Comment: Nayuki - very interesting suggestions, especially Soundex, I had not heard of that.

Comment: Usually it is called spellchecking or fuzzy search.